# How to pull Last and First name in Last, First format from user given input using scanner method

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter name (Last, First) and Social Security Number (###-##-####); ");
String name = in.next();
String info = in.nextLine();
```

User input looks like `Last, First 555-55-1234`

I need account to look like Last, First and account file to be lastfir1234.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: share the complete code u have tried so far?

Comment: Can you clarify the exact form the expected user input looks like?  The prompt is confusing.  (Alternatively, prompt the user for one thing at a time instead of trying to take it all in at once.)

Comment: Why not use `in.next()` to get last name and then first name. Call it twice, and then call `in.nextLine()`. This is more an exercise in logic than in coding.

Comment: the input you want is "Doe, John" enter "123-56-7890" from the user? What data type do want to store the social security number? String? Double?

Comment: Prompt them for separate things (name, SSN) separately. And show your Scanner setup, since your choice of delimiters affects how it operates. The given code is rubbish.

Comment: what on earth is `account file`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  int x=name.indexOf(',');
  int y=name.lastIndexOf('-');
  int z=name.lastIndexOf(' ');      

  account=name.substring(0,x)+name.substring(x+2,z)+name.substring(y+1,name.length());
```